# can i style an element if universal selector has particular property-value combination?

Tags: css, css-selectors

It's specifically for `text-spacing` styling. I want to set the element to auto height/width of the letter-spacing/word-spacing has some specific value.

**HTML**

```html
<span class="subjectText">this is the text</span>
```

**universal selector**

```
*{
  letter-spacing:1.641px;
}
```

**desired styling**

```
*[style*="letter-spacing:1.614px"] .subjectText{
     background-color:yellow;
}
```

I tried below,but its not working

```
*[style*="letter-spacing:1.614px"] .subjectText{
     background-color:yellow;
}
```

Comment: No, you can't do that. `[attr*="value"]` is for HTML attributes, not for CSS rules.

Comment: You can’t do this with pure CSS but will need some JavaScript. Is that allowed?

Comment: thanks @InSync and @A Haworth, Javascript is frowned upon as it adds to the processing post page load.

Answer (score 0):

The CSS selector will select any element with a style attribute containing the value "letter-spacing:1.614px" and any descendant with the class .subjectText. However, it won't work in your case because the style attribute is not defined on the span element itself, but rather on the universal selector.

you can define a separate class for the letter-spacing and apply it to the parent element of the text:

```css
.text-spacing {
  letter-spacing: 1.641px;
}

.text-spacing > .subjectText {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: thanks, but the letter-spacing is added via * (universal selector) *{letter-spacing:1.641px} not via a class.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED**

The short answer: Currently there is now way to test individual *properties* of defined CSS rules and use their value to define further CSS rules. Regardless whether they are defined with a *universal* or a *specific* selector, the CSS *attribute selector* mechanism simply does not incorporate testing for *properties*.

A simple test shows that it will work for **inline style attributes**, but you need to add `!important` to the properties you want to override as *inline style attributes* (`<tag style=".." />`) have precedence over *in document styles* (`<head><style>...</style></head>`).

In the current construction the **'*'-universal selector** is even [OPTIONAL] as the `[attribute]` selector rule is common enough.

BE AWARE, though, that the CSS attribute rule `[style*="..."]` must exactly match the tags `style="..."` assignment. It will fail when not an exact match.

```css
/* Testing any CSS property will NOT work */
 *                       { color: orange }
[style*="color: orange"] { color: black }

/* Testing the inline 'style' attribute will work */
[style*="color: red"]   { color: black !important }
[style*="color: green"] { font-weight: bold; color: black }
[style*="color: blue"]  { color: black }

h3 { color: black }
```

```html
<h3>for this to work, '*'-universal selector in the CSS is not required:</h3>

<p>This is the first test line. It is 'orange' and will not become 'black' as the CSS required by OP does not work.</p><p style="color: red">This is a test line. It is 'red', but will become 'black' when CSS rule is successful.</p>
<p style="color: green">This is also a test line. It is 'green' and will become 'bold' as there is no inline `font-weight` setting, but not 'black' by lack of '!important'.</p>
<p style="color: blue">This is also a test line. It is 'blue' and will not become 'black' by lack of '!important'.</p>
```

Comment: thanks Rene Van Der Lende, but perhaps I couldnt explain my requirement better, this fiddle explains what I am trying to achieve. https://jsfiddle.net/q2Lc7xjz/

Comment: @Ashutosh I understood what you meant, but I somehow messed up and omitted some explanation and example. Sorry for that!